# Simple range slider with 2 decimals

Tags: jquery

Im creating this simple range slider and I've found one on here that I like, and works for me. But I'm trying to get the price to display two decimals after the `.` and replace the `.` with a `,`.

I've read about `(.toFixed(2))`. But I have no idea how and where to place this. Since I found the code on here, I hope someone here could help me out. I have tried to put this `.toFixed(2)` in all the (probably wrong) places, but no luck.

I hope someone could help me with this. I hope it's not to much to ask. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I'm using.

```js
        $(document).ready(function($) {
          var itemtype = "item-1";
        
          $('.item-type').click(function() {
            $('.item-type').removeClass('item-type-active');
            $(this).addClass('item-type-active');
            itemtype = $(this).data('id');
            $('.calc-count').text($('.calc-range').val());
            rangeCalc($('.calc-range').val());
          });
        
          function rangeCalc(i) {
            var totalPrice = 0;
            var tariff = {
              "item-1": [{
                "begin": 1,
                "price": 29.50
              }, {
                "begin": 10,
                "price": 27.50
              }, {
                "begin": 15,
                "price": 24.50
              }, {
                "begin": 25,
                "price": 22.50
              }, {
                "begin": 40,
                "price": 20.50
              }, {
                "begin": 50,
                "price": 19.50
              }]
            };
        
            tariff[itemtype].forEach(function(num, item) {
              if (tariff[itemtype][item].begin <= i) {
                totalPrice = tariff[itemtype][item].price;
                $('.calc-total-price').text(i * totalPrice);
                $('.calc-price').text(totalPrice);
              };
              //console.log(tariff[item].begin);
            });
          };
        
          $('.calc-range').on('input', function() {
            $('.calc-count').text(this.value);
            rangeCalc(this.value);
          });
        
          //rangeCalc();
        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
         <input class="calc-range m-top-20" type="range" min="1" max="300" step="1" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="calc-count">1</div>
         Total price: <span class="calc-total-price"></span>
        <br> Price per item: <span class="calc-price"></span>
```

Comment: Try this out. `$('.calc-count').text(Number($('.calc-range')).val().toFixed(2));`

Comment: Alas, no go. That did not change to 2 decimal. But thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you play arround with values as number and try to set its toFixed values, sometimes its tricky, since it reads val as a string, and you cant play around with int function on a string. In this case it is recomended to allways pre set the number to Number format, there you go.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var itemtype = "item-1";

  $('.item-type').click(function() {
    $('.item-type').removeClass('item-type-active');
    $(this).addClass('item-type-active');
    itemtype = $(this).data('id');
    $('.calc-count').text($('.calc-range').val());
    rangeCalc($('.calc-range').val());
  });

  function rangeCalc(i) {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var tariff = {
      "item-1": [{
        "begin": 1,
        "price": 29.50
      }, {
        "begin": 10,
        "price": 27.50
      }, {
        "begin": 15,
        "price": 24.50
      }, {
        "begin": 25,
        "price": 22.50
      }, {
        "begin": 40,
        "price": 20.50
      }, {
        "begin": 50,
        "price": 19.50
      }]
    };

    tariff[itemtype].forEach(function(num, item) {
      if (tariff[itemtype][item].begin <= i) {
        totalPrice = tariff[itemtype][item].price;
        var total_price_CTP = Number(i * totalPrice).toFixed(2);
        totalPrice = Number(totalPrice).toFixed(2);
        $('.calc-total-price').text(total_price_CTP);
        $('.calc-price').text(totalPrice);
      };
      //console.log(tariff[item].begin);
    });
  };

  $('.calc-range').on('input', function() {
    $('.calc-count').text(this.value);
    rangeCalc(this.value);
  });

  //rangeCalc();

});
```

Ive tested it with jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dh45rqzy/1/

---

Updated fiddle with , instead of . https://jsfiddle.net/dh45rqzy/2/

I would recommend to replace `.` to `,` only when you are sure you are only displaying it (Which is the case now), since further more, if you are planning on doing some recalculations again, it wont work out.

These are the lines I've done some tweaking to.

```
$('.calc-total-price').text(total_price_CTP);
$('.calc-price').text(totalPrice);
    //To ->
$('.calc-total-price').text(total_price_CTP.replace('.',','));
$('.calc-price').text(totalPrice.replace('.',','));
```

Comment: Excellent! This works like a charm! Thanks a lot, and the clear explanation. Maybe you know how to change the `.` into a `,` as well?